# Database First Как из БД создать модели в VS19?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-core

Создаю консольное приложение net core 3.1.
Если я правильно понимаю то в EFcore 5 нет инструментов для Database First.
Мб есть какие расширения для автоматического создания моделей?

Comment: используй консольную команду (она не привязана к студии): `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <CONNECTION> <PROVIDER>` вот статья на MDSN: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используй консольную команду (она не привязана к студии): `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <CONNECTION> <PROVIDER>`
[вот статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) с доп. параметрами для этой команды и другими полезными командами *(например, создание миграции и ее применение к БД)*